# Firebase technique to find nearest users

Tags: android, firebase, google-maps

I want to make a search bar which shows items i search for, sorted according to distance, using firebase.

I have made realtime databse on firebase which will store personal details.
next feature i want to include is a search bar which searches for nearest user.

Comment: Please tell us what you have tried so far and where you were stuck so that we can help.

Comment: please refer - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask